Is it possible to download a single file from ZIP artifact in Jenkins?
Say I have some job which produces an artifact which is a ZIP file.
I can certainly download the whole artifact via the special link.
Is it possible to download one of the files from the ZIP artifact directly?
By 'directly' I mean not by downloading the whole ZIP artifact and then unzipping the needed file.
Something, which on TeamCity is possible via the ...<artifact.zip>!<path/within/archive> syntax.
